# jquery - How to remove other div classes

Tags: jquery, removeclass

Suppose I have 5 div classes named `.content` inside a div with an id `#container`. I want to remove the first 4 and leave only the last one. How am I suppose to do it in jquery?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content"> </div>
    <div class="content"> </div>
    <div class="content"> </div>
    <div class="content"> </div>
    <div class="content"> </div>
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the appropriate selector as well.

```
$(".content:not(:last-child)").remove();
```

Meaning every `.content` div except the one that are the last child of their parents.

Comment: Py's answer is a good way to do it in case the number of content divs is dynamic. See similar example: http://jsfiddle.net/dTZrB/

Answer (score 2):

Using `.slice`:

```
$('#container').children('.content').slice(0, 4).remove()
```

Or using selectors in `.children()`:

```
​$('#container').children('.content:lt(4)').remove()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Update**

To remove all but the last child:

```
$('#container').children('.content').slice(0, -1).remove()
```

Using `slice()` has the advantage that you can select the last two children easily by using `(0, -2)` as the range.

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot No problem, I'm now heading off to log a bug report for jQuery :)

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot Okay, it turns out that `.slice(0, -1)` works okay; just fyi

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the best way to do it.

> $(".content:not(:last-child)").removeClass("content");